# Java calculations that takes X amount of time

Tags: java, android, math

This is just a hypothetical question, but could be a way to get around an issue I have been having.

Imagine you want to be able to time a calculation function based not on the answer, but on the time it takes to calculating. So instead of finding out what a + b is, you wish to continue perform some calculation while time < x seconds.

Look at this pseudo code:

```
public static void performCalculationsForTime(int seconds)
{
     // Get start time
     int millisStart = System.currentTimeMillis();

     // Perform calculation to find the 1000th digit of PI
     // Check if the given amount of seconds have passed since millisStart
     // If number of seconds have not passed, redo the 1000th PI digit calculation

     // At this point the time has passed, return the function.
}
```

Now I know that I am horrible, despicable person for using precious CPU cycles to simple get time to pass, but what I am wondering is:
A) Is this possible and would JVM start complaining about non-responsiveness?
B) If it is possible, what calculations would be best to try to perform?

**Update - Answer**:
Based on the answers and comments, the answer seems to be that "Yes, this is possible. But only if it is *not* done in Android main UI thread, because the user's GUI will be become unresponsive and will throw an ANR after 5 seconds."

Comment: You dealing with long calculations in the main thread (aka UI-Thread). This is not the best approach. Better use a Handler / doInBackground()... 
 If you block the UI-Thread for 5 sec. a ANR will be fired. 
Working with doubles and floats takes much longer then a multiplication by 4 (which is a 2er bitshift)
decimal -> bin: 5 -> 101 so 4 = 2^2 and 5*4 = 20... Bitshifting 101 by 2 positions to the left will be 10100 = 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> A) Is this possible and would JVM start complaining about non-responsiveness?

It is possible, and if you run it in the background, neither JVM nor Dalvik will complain.

> B) If it is possible, what calculations would be best to try to perform?

If the objective is to just run any calculation for x seconds, just keep adding 1 to a sum until the required time has reached. Off the top of my head, something like:

```
public static void performCalculationsForTime(int seconds)
{ 
 // Get start time 
 int secondsStart = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
 int requiredEndTime = millisStart + seconds;
 float sum = 0;

 while(secondsStart != requiredEndTime) {
   sum = sum + 0.1;
   secondsStart = System.currentTimeMillis()/1000;
 }
}
```

Comment: What if I'm asking the Android main UI thread to execute this? (Of course with a cancellation possibility.)
Would Dalvik complain then?

Comment: Yes it will. Your app will hang and you will get an 'App Not Responding' (ANR) message.

Comment: It will hang? Even if, let's say, I show a Dialog box with a Cancellation option?
(Even as I wrote this, my thoughts are that it will still need to perform the last calculation before be able to cancel. So ANR.)

Comment: Even if you have a cancellation option, since you're running your code on the Main thread (on which the UI runs), Android will not be able to process the click on the cancel button until the above code completes execution. If any piece of code takes too long to complete on the Main thread, Dalvik shows an ANR. The only way to make it 'cancellable' is to run it on a separate thread (or AsyncTask) and cancel that task on click of the button. Since you're now running your code on a separate thread (not Main UI thread), the 'click' will get processed and your AsyncTask should cancel.

Answer (score 2):

You can and JVM won't complain *if your code is not part of some complex system that actually tracks thread execution time*.

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while(System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 100000) {
    // do something
}
```

Or even a `for` loop that checks time only every 1000 cycles.

```
for (int i = 0; ;i++) {
    if (i % 1000 == 0 && System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime < 100000)
        break;
    // do something
}
```

As for your second question, the answer is probably calculating some value that can always be improved upon, like your PI digits example.